# Numeric Dynamic Number in Paw Request

Tags: paw-app

Using Paw, I've got a Dynamic Value that returns a number, and I want to use that in the body of a JSON request. However when I go to the row in my request body and right click I don't see all of the options to set a dynamic value if the type is set to Number. It's all there if the type is set to String.

Context menu for a string:

[image: Context menu for a string]

Context menu for a number:

[image: Context menu for a number]

Is there a way to do what I'm after?

Comment: It's actually a known issue or more exactly a missing feature. In fact, it's not possible to insert dynamic values (including request variables) in JSON fields of types number or boolean. It's something we're going to add in a future version of Paw.